# How to iterate through a csv file and update value based on the value of another

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv file with one column with the header 'size' that is blank for each value of the csv file. I have three values of size, 1, 2, and 3. I want to update this empty column with the corresponding value of another variable 'time'. I want rows with a 'time' value between 0-100 to have a size of 1, rows with a 'time' value between 101-200 to be 2, and for the rest to be 3. I have attached the data and some code I have tried. Thank you so much!
[image]

```
for row in data.iterrows():
    if data['time']<=100:
        data['size']=1
    elif 100<data['time']<200:
        data['size']=2
    else:
        data['size']='3'
```

But that gives me `'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above does not reference the line that the for loop is iterating through. The code below references the line via the index of the df as it is iterating through the rows.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if df.loc[index, 'Time'] <= 100:
      df.loc[index, 'Size'] = 1
   elif 100 < df.loc[index, 'Time'] < 200:
      df.loc[index, 'Size'] = 2
   else:
      df.loc[index, 'Size'] = 3
```